# How to use pyspark in pycharm to connect to the graph database and call the graph algorithm？

Tags: nebula-graph

How to use `pyspark` in `pycharm` to connect to the graph database and call the graph algorithm? Is there such `api`?

Also,may I ask how the object `class 'py4j.java_gateway.JavaObject'` after calling the graph algorithm is converted back to the `pyspark` dataframe object `class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in this way:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

jdf = jdf.toDF()
df = DataFrame(jdf, spark)
```